# html_entity_decode() isn't work (PHP)

Tags: php, utf-8

html_entity_decode() return back HTML entities, not an applicable characters.

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8">
<?php

$code='&#97'; // It's a code of 'a' UTF-8 character.

$char = html_entity_decode($code, ENT_COMPAT, $encoding = 'UTF-8');

/*
Now $char must contains 'a' value, but it contains '&#97';

You can check this by following tests
*/

var_dump('&#97' === 'a');      // bool(false), of course.
var_dump('&#97' === $code);    // bool(true)
var_dump('&#97' === $char);    // bool(true) BUT MUST BE FALSE
var_dump($code === $char);     // bool(true) BUT MUST BE FALSE

// Or this:

echo str_replace('&', '', $char);    // it must print 'a', but it print '#97'
```

Looks like this function do nothing in my case.
What's wrong?

Comment: Your character reference is missing the delimiting `;`: `&#97;`.

Comment: PHP isn't Python, it doesn't have named parameters. `$encoding = 'UTF-8'` probably doesn't do what you think it does. The function call should be simply `html_entity_decode($code, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&#97` is not the "code of 'a' UTF-8 character.".

However, `&#97;` is. Use that and your code will work as expected.